# Ember.js open a single item in a list of collapsed items

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an app that has a dashboard. On the dashboard is a list of the 5 most recent reminders. On another page is a list of all the reminders where the details are collapsed. Clicking on a reminder opens the details of the reminder using an accordion effect.

I'm wondering if there is a way to have the user click on a reminder on the dashboard and be taken to the list of all the reminders with the one reminder the user clicked on expanded. Is that type of deep linking possible in Ember?

Comment: Maybe use query params

Comment: I worked through the problem with the UX team. Now I can go to a page with an individual reminder listed instead of all of them. This means I don't have to have a specific reminder open when the list of reminders loads.

Answer (score 0):

I worked through the problem with the UX team. Now I can go to a page with an individual reminder listed instead of all of them. This means I don't have to have a specific reminder open when the list of reminders loads.